# Use S3 presigned URL with VichUploader

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, vichuploaderbundle

I am able to use the PHP Symfony bundle Vich-Uploader to upload files to a **private bucket** in Amazon S3, via the php sdk *Flysystem* adapter.

How can I get a signed/presigned URL for a key, after the upload?

I can load the plugin into *Flysystem*, but Vich won't use the [`$filesystem->getPresignedUrl('/tmp/some/target')`](https://github.com/sistemi-etime/flysystem-plugin-aws-s3-v3) method.

Is this supported by the bundle in any way? Or what class should be extended and registered in order to call the *presignedURL* method correctly?

Comment: I ended up extending the VichUploader FlysystemStorage, override the `resolveUri` method to `return $filesystem->getPresignedUrl($path)` and then override the `vich_uploader.storage.flysystem` with the custom storage class, into `services.yaml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct way into *VichUploader*, but it is possible to tell Symfony to use a custom Storage and add the plugin logic inside there.

## Install presigned-URLs plugin for Flysystem

```
composer require sistemi-etime/flysystem-plugin-aws-s3-v3
```

Use the plugin with the Flysystem, via the bundle `oneup_flysystem.yaml` config:

```
oneup_flysystem:
    filesystems:
        aws_s3:
            ...
            ...
            plugins:
                - s3.plugin.presigned_url
```

## Define your own Storage

```
<?php

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Storage\FlysystemStorage;

class CustomFlysystemStorage extends FlysystemStorage
{
    // Copy the parent method code but then return the presigned URL
    public function resolveUri($obj, ?string $fieldName = null, ?string $className = null)
    {
        [$mapping, $filename] = $this->getFilename($obj, $fieldName, $className);

        if (empty($filename)) {
            return null;
        }

        $dir = $mapping->getUploadDir($obj);
        $path = !empty($dir) ? $dir.'/'.$filename : $filename;

        $fs = $this->getFilesystem($mapping, $obj, $fieldName, $className);

        return $fs->getPresignedUrl($path);
    }
}
```

## Make use of it inside `services.yaml`:

```
# alias the custom storage to be used instead of the one defined by VichUploader
vich_uploader.storage.flysystem: '@Your\Own\Namespace\CustomFlysystemStorage'
```

---

### Fix autowiring (why? ‍♂️)

*[Edit: [that's why](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade/service-deprecations#strict-autowiring-mode)]*

Additionally I had to *explicitly alias the arguments required* by the `FlysystemStorage` in order for Symfony Autowire to initialise the custom storage:

```
Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\PropertyMappingFactory: '@vich_uploader.property_mapping_factory'
League\Flysystem\MountManager: '@oneup_flysystem.mount_manager'
```

Although I am **not sure why this was necessary**.

I would expect that either `vich_uploader.property_mapping_factory` and `oneup_flysystem.mount_manager` are already defined and aliased by the configs from [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/f24c3a1764d30cbe6e7d4d8bbc2daca6f0c2693e/config/factory.xml#L14) and [OneupFlysystemBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/fe7286d9d025c3a4a66d40e4fb626c2ee8b51aa6/Resources/config/flysystem.xml#L7)

If anybody knows how to skip this fix, please comment.